# What does it mean? <bound method Circle.calcArea of <__main__.Circle object at 0x034E4070>>

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code and no idea why this error throw :

```
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius=radius

    def calcPerimeter(radius):
        calcPerimeter=2*(math.pi)*radius

    def calcArea(radius):
        calcArea=(math.pi)*(radius)^2

    def __str__(self):
        msg="radius: "+str(self.radius)+" Area: "+str(self.calcArea)+" Perimeter: "+str(self.calcPerimeter)
        return msg

c1=Circle(100)
print(c1)
```

I get this error:

```
radius: 100 Area: <bound method Circle.calcArea of <__main__.Circle object at 0x034E4070>> Perimeter: <bound method Circle.calcPerimeter of <__main__.Circle object at 0x034E4070>>
```

And I want the result:

```
radius: 100 Area: 31415.92 Perimeter: 628.3184
```

Comment: Also there are several other problems. (1) you need to add a `self` parameter to the methods or make them `staticmethods`; (2) you need to *return* something from the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python all methods need self as their first argument (unless static methods) and if you do not do something using `self.property = "value"` you should return something to make your methods useful.

As a bonus for improving this code, look up [property decorators](https://youtu.be/jCzT9XFZ5bw) and [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
import math


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def calcPerimeter(self):
        return 2 * (math.pi) * self.radius

    def calcArea(self):
        return (math.pi) * (self.radius) ** 2

    def __str__(self):
        msg = "radius: " + str(self.radius) + " Area: " + str(self.calcArea()) + " Perimeter: " + str(self.calcPerimeter())
        return msg


c1 = Circle(100)
print(c1)
```

Comment: Im so happy to meet you very thank you have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually calling the method, just passing the method itself to `str`.

```
msg="radius: "+str(self.radius)+" Area: "+str(self.calcArea(self.radius))+" Perimeter: "+str(self.calcPerimeter(self.radius))
```

Comment: thank you but I have no idea on your suggestion..... Another error occurs..

Comment: This is supposed to replace the `msg = ...` line from your code snippet. Please post the error or even better the full code producing the error.

Comment: For this to work you still have to have self as the first parameter for the methods.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure to add self as a first argument in methods within class
2 - Also do add self with new variables you created in methods
"""
for example: self.msg
and then return self.msg """

**Here is the Correct Version of Code:**

```
import math

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius=radius

    def calcPerimeter(self):
        self.calcPerimeter=float(2*(math.pi)*self.radius)
        return self.calcPerimeter

    def calcArea(self):
        self.calcArea=float((math.pi)*(self.radius)**2)
        return self.calcArea

    def display_Results(self):
        self.msg = "radius: "+str(self.radius)+" Area: "+str(self.calcArea)+" 
        Perimeter: "+str(self.calcPerimeter)
        return self.msg


c1=Circle(100)
print(f"Perimeter = {c1.calcPerimeter()}")
print(f"Area = {c1.calcArea()}")
print(c1.display_Results())
```